# MongoDB - Fetch an object from deep subdocuments

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How to query an object from an Array inside an Array, and get it as a top-level object? For example, consider the following record.

```
{
  "subjects": [
         {
             "name": "English",
             "teachers": [
                  {
                    "name": "Mark"   /* Trying to get this object*/
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "John"
                  }
              ]
         }
   ]
}
```

I am trying to get the following object out as the top-level object.

```
{
   "name": "Mark"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) framework to do exactly what you're asking for.

Here I entered the document you gave into collection: foo.

```
> db.foo.find().pretty()

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57ceed3d31484d5b491eaae9"),
    "subjects" : [
        {
            "name" : "English",
            "teachers" : [
                {
                    "name" : "Mark"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "John"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Using $unwind to unravel our array we then enter our first stage of the aggregation pipeline:

```
> db.foo.aggregate([
...     {$unwind: "$subjects"}
... ]).pretty()

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57ceed3d31484d5b491eaae9"),
    "subjects" : {
        "name" : "English",
        "teachers" : [
            {
                "name" : "Mark"
            },
            {
                "name" : "John"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Subjects was an array of length 1 so the only difference here is one less set of  [] array brackets.

We need to unwind again.

```
> db.foo.aggregate([
...     {$unwind: "$subjects"},
...     {$unwind: "$subjects.teachers"}
... ]).pretty()

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57ceed3d31484d5b491eaae9"),
    "subjects" : {
        "name" : "English",
        "teachers" : {
            "name" : "Mark"
        }
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57ceed3d31484d5b491eaae9"),
    "subjects" : {
        "name" : "English",
        "teachers" : {
            "name" : "John"
        }
    }
}
```

Now we turned our array of length '2' into two separate documents.  The first one with subjects.teachers.name = Mark and the second with subjects.teachers.name = John.

We only want to return the case where name = Mark so we need to add a $match stage to our pipeline.

```
> db.foo.aggregate([
...     {$unwind: "$subjects"},
...     {$unwind: "$subjects.teachers"},
...     {$match: {"subjects.teachers.name": "Mark"}}
... ]).pretty()

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57ceed3d31484d5b491eaae9"),
    "subjects" : {
        "name" : "English",
        "teachers" : {
            "name" : "Mark"
        }
    }
}
```

Ok!  Now we are only matching on the case where name: Mark.

Let's add a $project case to shape our input how we want.

```
> db.foo.aggregate([
...     {$unwind: "$subjects"},
...     {$unwind: "$subjects.teachers"},
...     {$match: {"subjects.teachers.name": "Mark"}},
...     {$project: {"name": "$subjects.teachers.name", "_id": 0}}
... ]).pretty()

{ "name" : "Mark" }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answered.

Comment: You have to use https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/#exp._S_literal

For instance:

    {$project: {"name": "$subjects.teachers.name", "_id": 0, "address": {$literal: "123 ABC"}}}

Comment: No. I mean to update the information into the collection. So that the collection becomes:

{
  "subjects": [
         {
             "name": "English",
             "teachers": [
                  {
                    "name": "Mark" ,
                    "address": "123 ABC XYZ"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "John"
                  }
              ]
         }
   ]
}

Comment: Aggregation isn't really a write operation in the Mongo Shell.  You'd have to execute this inside your server code and pass the results into a callback function where you can then do your manipulation and resave the documents.